# Add more than one element to set content view

Tags: java, android, layout, setcontentview

i have a app set up which loads a website into the app which works fine, when i try to add another element to the content view the app crashes without a error, How can i add more than one element to my set content view? ive tried it with frame layout and more but they all dont seem to work.
Here is my code

```
package com.example.fiercepcs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.fiercepcs.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;



import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.app.Application;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);







        LinearLayout screenLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        screenLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);




        WebView myWebView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.fiercepc.co.uk");

       
        setContentView(myWebView);
        setContentView(button);
    }




}
```

my activity main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FiercePcs.AppBarOverlay" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:translationZ="-5dp">

    </WebView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="179dp"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="1"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your app crashes because your are trying to set **button** view and **webView** as the root layout, don't do that, inflate or bind the root of your layout with **ActivityMainBinding**

do it like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        bindnig = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)






        LinearLayout screenLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        screenLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);




        WebView myWebView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.fiercepc.co.uk");

        
    }




}
```

Comment: also use binding object instead of using findViewById, binding object makes it easier and sexy :) @kingcannibal